# trigger while form button is depressed

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone point me to the right direction? I'm trying to get a loop to trigger while the form button is depressed.

//pseudocode While (button1 is pressed) value1 += 1 And then stop looping when the button is released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid using threads you can add a `Timer` component on your form/control and try enabling it on mouse down and disable it on mouse up. Then put the code you would normally put inside the loop in the `Timer_Tick event`.